# Bootstrap NavBar display Issue

Tags: html

My Nav bar is not displaying properly.the menus are stacking over another.Could anyone please help me to rule out the issue.i'm attaching the codes i used and also the current display of navbar in browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>New Website</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">New WebSite</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
     <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add CSS plz in code.